# Thomas Algorithm in Python and Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

Python code:

```
import math
import numpy
n = input('Enter the dimension')
print 'Matrix size',n    
dd = [
     0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
    30,31,
    ]
k,l,m = input ("enter vectors")
aa=[]
bb=[]
cc=[]
for i in range(n+1):
    bb.append(l)
for i in range(n):
    aa.append(k)
    cc.append(m)
a = numpy.array(aa)
b = numpy.array(bb)
c = numpy.array(cc)
d = numpy.array(dd)
c[0] = c[0]/ b[0]
d[0] = d[0]/ b[0]
for i in range(1,n,1):
    c[i] = c[i]/(b[i] - a[i] * c[i-1])
for i in range(1,n,1):
     d[i] = (d[i] - a[i] * d[i-1])/(b[i] - a[i] * c[i-1])
d[-1] = (d[-1] - a[-1] * d[-2])/( b[-1] - a[-1] * c[-2])
x = numpy.zeros(n)
x[-1] = d[-1]
for i in range(-2, -n, -1):
   x[i] = d[i] - c[i] * x[i + 1]
print x
```

Fortran code:

```
integer,parameter::dp=selected_real_kind(15)
integer,intent(in)::n
real(dp),dimension(n),intent(in)::a,b,c,d
real(dp),dimension(n),intent(out)::x
integer::i
real(dp),dimension(n)::c_k,d_k
c_k(1)=c(1)/b(1)
d_k(1)=d(1)/b(1)
do i=2,n-1
c_k(i)=c(i)/(b(i)-c_k(i-1)*a(i))
end do
do i=2,n
d_k(i)=(d(i)-d_k(i-1)*a(i))/(b(i)-c_k(i-1)*a(i))
end do
x(n)=d_k(n)
do i=n-1,1,-1
x(i)=d_k(i)-c_k(i)*x(i+1)
end do
end subroutine thomas_algorithm
```

I have these codes for the Thomas Algorithm in Python and Fortran respectively. But when Python gives the result

```
[  0.   1.   1.   1.   2.   2.   2.   3.   3.   3.   4.   4.   4.   5.   5.
   5.   6.   6.   6.   7.   7.   7.   8.   8.   8.   9.   9.   9.  10.  10.
  10.]
```

for x, Fortran gives

```
1 4.996003610813204E-016
2 0.999999999999999
3 1.554312234475219E-015
4 2.00000000000000
5 2.664535259100376E-015
6 3.00000000000000
7 4.440892098500626E-015
8 3.99999999999999
9 6.217248937900877E-015
10 4.99999999999999
11 7.105427357601002E-015
12 5.99999999999999
13 8.881784197001252E-015
14 6.99999999999999
15 1.065814103640150E-014
16 7.99999999999999
17 1.243449787580175E-014
18 6.99999999999999
19 1.421085471520200E-014
20 5.99999999999998
21 1.509903313490213E-014
22 4.99999999999999
23 1.287858708565182E-014
24 3.99999999999999
25 1.021405182655144E-014
26 2.99999999999999
27 7.993605777301127E-015
28 1.99999999999999
29 4.884981308350689E-015
30 0.999999999999997
31 1.613292832658430E-015
```

What is the reason of this difference?

Note : in Python I am taking sub and main diagonal entries from keyboard.

Comment: Format it, shorten it, explain what a Thomas algorithm is, state your case...

Comment: Please format your code (see `{}` symbol when you edit), and explain your problem in addition to the code.

Comment: Post the entire fortran code (that subroutine is missing at least the first few rows), preferably with the test program. Put something shorter in fortran's write format. Check for division errors in py code, like Ethan said. ...

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that work for you (click on the green checkmark by them).

Answer (score 3):

In your Python code try putting `from __future__ import division` at the top.  I suspect you are currently getting integer division.

Comment: That would explain some of these errors, but not the value of 10 in the resultant list.  No value (quick glance) seems to even come close to rounding to that, so I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: yes ethan the problem was division. but from __future__ import division did not work so I used floating the array elements

Comment: @Brhn: Ah, you must be using an older Python.